# AngularJs ng-model delay between controller and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJs and ng-model, there is a big delay from controller to UI. In the `$scope.selectedRisk` I have this problem, before the modal show the variable is correct but when the modal is opened the old value is showed and after few second (I think the $inteval time) I can see the correct value.
This is the angularjs code (I post the all code but the problem is in the end):

```
'use strict';

//$routeParams allows to retrieve the parameters passe by url
app.controller('asocAdminController', ['$scope','$http','$routeParams', '$filter', 'toastService', '$interval', 'riskService', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $filter, toastService, $interval, riskService)  {

    const TIMING_SYNCHRONIZE = 5000;
    $scope.counterError = 0;
    $scope.selectedRisk={};
    $scope.likelihood = {};
    const MAX_ERROR = 3;
    $scope.mqtt = {status:true,message:"Service running"};
    /*
     * Retrieve the mqtt status
     */
    $scope.mqttStatusFunction = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/mqtt/',
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (typeof response.data.success == 'undefined'){
                window.location.href = "/500";
            }else if (response.data.success==true){
                $scope.mqtt.status = response.data.result;
                if ($scope.mqtt.status===true)
                    $scope.mqtt.message = "Service running";
                else if ($scope.mqtt.status===false)
                    $scope.mqtt.message = "Service not running";
                else
                    $scope.mqtt.message = "Service unknow";                     
            }else if (response.data.success==false){
                notifyMessage(response.data.result, 'error');
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.counterError++;
            if (counterError === MAX_ERROR){
                $('#errorConnectionModal').modal('show');
            }else {
                $scope.mqttStatusFunction();
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.likelihoodFunction = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/likelihood/',
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (typeof response.data.success == 'undefined'){
                window.location.href = "/500";
            }else if (response.data.success==true){
                $scope.likelihood = response.data.result;
            }else if (response.data.success==false){
                notifyMessage(response.data.result, 'error');
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.counterError++;
            if (counterError === MAX_ERROR){
                $('#errorConnectionModal').modal('show');
            }else {
                $scope.likelihoodFunction();
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.tableInitialize = function(){
        //initialize datatable
        $scope.riskTable = $('#riskTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            paging : false,
            order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            info: false,
            searching: false,
            select: {
                style: 'os',
                items: 'cell'
            },
            "ajax":{ 
                "url": "/risk/",
                "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                    if (typeof json.success == 'undefined')
                        location.reload();
                    else if (json.success){
                        return json.result;
                    }else{
                        notifyMessage(json.result, 'error');   
                        return "";
                    }                           
                },  
                "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {data:null, 
                    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return data[0].severity;
                    }
                },
                {data:null, 
                    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return  riskService.riskIcon(data[0].value);
                    }
                },
                {data:null, 
                    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return  riskService.riskIcon(data[1].value);
                    }
                },
                {data:null, 
                    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return  riskService.riskIcon(data[2].value);
                    }
                },
//              { 
//                  data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
//                      return '<span style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green" name="modifyRisk"></i></span>';
//                  }
//
//              },
            ],
        });
    }

    $('#riskTable').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
        let cell =$scope.riskTable.cell( this );
        $scope.selectedRisk = cell.data()[cell.index().column] ;
        $('#editRiskModal').modal('show');
    } );



    //Main
    $scope.mqttStatusFunction();
    $interval($scope.mqttStatusFunction,TIMING_SYNCHRONIZE);
    $scope.likelihoodFunction();
    $scope.tableInitialize();
}]);
```

The HTML(I'm using angular routing to make a single page application):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.color-red {
    color: red
}

.color-green {
    color: green
}

.color-grey {
    color: grey
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>SAP</h1>            
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                                <div
                                    data-ng-class="{'box box-success': mqtt.status == true, 'box box-danger': mqtt.status == false, 'box box-warning': mqtt.status == null}">
                                    <!-- form start -->
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                            <span
                                                data-ng-class="{'info-box-icon bg-red': mqtt.status == false, 'info-box-icon bg-orange': mqtt.status == null, 'info-box-icon bg-green': mqtt.status == true}"><i
                                                data-ng-class="{'fa fa-check': mqtt.status == true, 'fa fa-times': mqtt.status == false, 'fa fa-question': mqtt.status == null}"
                                                aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <div class="info-box-content">
                                                <span class="info-box-text" style="font-size: 25px;">{{mqtt.message}}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="box box-info">
                                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                                        <h3 class="box-title">Likelihood</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                                    <!-- form start -->
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="likelihoodA" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A</label>

                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="likelihoodA"
                                                            data-ng-model="likelihood.a" min="0" max="100"> <span
                                                            class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="likelihoodB" class="col-sm-2 control-label">B</label>

                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="likelihoodB"
                                                            data-ng-model="likelihood.b" min="0" max="100"> <span
                                                            class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                                        <div class="box-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.box-footer -->
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="box box-info">
                                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                                        <h3 class="box-title">Risk table</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                                    <!-- form start -->
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                            <table id="riskTable"
                                                class="table table-bordered table-striped"
                                                style="width: 100%;">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Severity</th>
                                                        <th>&lt;A</th>
                                                        <th>A&lt;x&lt;B</th>
                                                        <th>&gt;B</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="modal" id="editRiskModal" data-backdrop="static"
        data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Risk editing</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="severityInput">Severity</label> <input
                                    class="form-control" id="severityInput" placeholder="severity" data-ng-model="selectedRisk.severity" disabled >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label> <input
                                    type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                                    aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
                                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll
                                    never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label> <input
                                    type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                                    placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="exit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button id="refresh" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is in the modal but if I put outside the problem still the same.
This is the first time I have this problem. Do you help me?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be `$("#riskTable").on("click", "td", function() {}`.

This is not a real problem, but AngularJs is not getting informed about the change.

To do so, you have to call `$scope.$applyAsync()` at the end of this function to initiate the `digest-cycle`.

```
$('#riskTable').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
  let cell =$scope.riskTable.cell( this );
  $scope.selectedRisk = cell.data()[cell.index().column] ;
  $('#editRiskModal').modal('show');

  $scope.$applyAsync();
});
```

**EDIT**
The delay is the time until the next `digest-cycle`.

Comment: I fixed with `$scope.$applyAsync();` at the end of  `$('#riskTable').on( 'click', 'td', function () {`

Comment: nice. I am really pleased.